# FireEvent after e.stop()

Tags: mootools

i have a form that i stop from submitting and when confirm message pops up and user clicks yes i want when that happens to submit the form,how can i do that?i tried using fireEvent like this but it wont work...in firebug it says e is undefined.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

var form=document.adminForm;
form.addEvent('submit', function(e){

var result=confirm("Are you sure!?");
e.stop();
if(result){
form.fireEvent("submit");  
}


});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to stop the event before the confirm and submit after. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/qAx6H/

```
var form=document.id('adminForm');

form.addEvent('submit', function(e){
    e && e.stop();

    if (confirm('Are you sure?')){
        this.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: when i try your e $$ e.stop() it doesnt stop the submit,and when i set only e.stop() i get an error e is undefined...

Comment: it works in jsfiddle. hence, your version of mootools is wrong. in older vers (1.1x), you had to do `new Event(e).stop();` instead.

Comment: the mootools is included in my joomla component,i checked earlier and it is 1.4.5...i tried event(e).stop() just in case but it is the same thing...

Comment: do you have an actual submit event or is something firing it synthetically via `.fireEvent`? any other event handlers on the form?

Comment: when i try just e.stop() i get e is undefined,when e && e.stop() i dont get any errors but the form doesnt stop,i also tried Event(e).stop() but then i get c is undefined...i cant believe that this is happening...:D

Comment: what you describe is observed when the event fires synthetically via `form.fireEvent('submit')` - which would imply the event handler is not responding to the native event.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question you want simple confirmation befor submittiong the form. If so, you can use this tiny script:

```
<input type="submit" OnClick="return confirm('Are you sure!?');" ... />
```

It will pop-up modal with Ok/Cancel buttons, but works fine for me.

Comment: i used confirm just as an example,the thing that i need is that i want to stop the form from submitting and then after user confirms, submit(fire) that form but when i use e.stop() i get an error e is undefined...